# Comment is above one with earlier timestamp

Tags: bug, comments, android-app

I posted a comment on an answer, and refreshed the page.  I then noticed that someone else had also posted a comment.  His comment had an earlier timestamp, but was below mine.

[image: screenshot]

What happened?  (I'm using the Android app, if that matters.)

Comment: Can you link the post please?

Comment: The post has since been deleted, but I still found it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37468809/5827958

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're basically just seeing a UI glitch re: merging data; perhaps it used the local device time for simulating a fast UI update for *your answer as you added it* ("fake it until you make it"), but basically: your comment *was genuinely there first*. You can see this in the main web app by hovering on the times; yours is 2016-05-26 18:49:32Z, the second one is 2016-05-26 18:49:45Z. Or at the database:

[image: database view of comment data]

So: the *only* thing wrong is the relative date displayed in the Android app *at the point the comment is first created*. In reality, it is a very edge condition; but we should keep it on the list to check whether we want to tweak the app to update itself with the times (etc.) *after they have been saved*.

Comment: So, [tag:status-added-to-list]?