# Inappropriate comment timestamps

Tags: feature-request, comments, android-app, timestamps

I observed that the timing of a comment was shown as *9 sec ago* and that of my reply to that comment was *26 sec ago*. How is this possible? Here is the screenshot:

> [image: See the last two comments]

I felt this was because the comment has been edited after I replied to it but there is no change in timestamp if a comment is edited. There needs to be different timing for **posting** and **editing**.

Comment: If it is due to editing comments then it's limited to the Android app. I don't have the Android app to check but I just checked on the web and iOS app and the timestamp doesn't reset when editing a comment (unless others' comments behave differently to your own)

Comment: Or it may just be this: [Comment is above one with earlier timestamp](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279698/comment-is-above-one-with-earlier-timestamp)

Comment: @Cai I think this problem is a different one as the reply to a comment is being posted. There is no role of android-app.  I have also tried editing comment. There's no change in timestamp.